# react-hooks/exhaustive-deps following rule causes bug. Not all dependencies should be watched?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint-plugin-react-hooks

I've got a search component that can be triggered two ways. One by a user typing (debounced), and one by a button to retry. `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`'s suggestion actually causes a bug for me, as watching `searchTerm` fires both effects, when I only want the first to fire. Is there another approach that I should take?

```
export default function Search(props) {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('')
  const [retryCounter, setRetryCounter] = useRetryCounter() // number (int) of manual retries

  function search() { ... }

  const debouncedSearch = useRef(lodash.debounce(search, 300, { maxWait: 500 })).current

  useEffect(() => {
    debouncedSearch(searchTerm)
  }, [searchTerm, debouncedSearch])
  // when `searchTerm` changes, a user has typed into an <input />, so do a debounced search

  useEffect(() => {
    // i want to continue using the `searchTerm` provided by the user preivously
    search(searchTerm)
  }, [retryCounter])
  // if i add `searchTerm` as a dep, then BOTH useEffects fire, and `search` gets fired twice.
  // therefore, i explicitly want to ignore changes to `searchTerm` here

  ...
  
  return (
    <>
      <input value={searchTerm} onChange={e => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={setRetryCounter}>retry</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

---

I also noticed [on the official discussion of this rule that @StevenMyers32's question was not addressed](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920#issuecomment-470735957) (he has a codesandbox example), and his example seems to be a similar problem of "if i include this dependency, useEffect will incorrectly fire".

Comment: It *is* just a warning, and the linter can't possibly know your specific use case. Options include: turn off that rule (not good), disable rule in file (also not good), disable rule for *that* line (not great, but makes warning go away. The issue with disabling the rule is if you later change the logic and add dependencies, if still disabled the linter won't and can't later catch bugs you introduce. Disabling for the line, with an additional comment to document why is about the best you can do, IMO.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using retryCount state at all? Why not `button onClick={() => search(searchTerm)}`?

Comment: @windowsill Excellent point. I hadn't actually looked at the content of the provided code snippet but it seems that would more simply achieve what OP is after.

Comment: My application is a little more complex, involving capturing/logging retry occurrences in `useRetryCounter`. I simplified it here for the sake of presentation.

Comment: I have disabled the rule for nextline right now. I'm hoping that @Dan Abramov (author of that github issue above) will see this and add this kind of use case to his nearly-exhaustive list of use-cases.

Comment: I think Gaearon's comment [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920#issuecomment-470863122) effectively summarizes his stance. `search` and `searchTerm` change over time, but if these changes are irrelevant for this effect then you "should add a lint rule ignore comment explaining why".

Comment: I still think it's incorrect to think of `retryCounter` as a dependency of invoking the `search` function, when clearly the only dependency is the button press. In other words, search doesn't really have anything to do with retryCount, but retryCount has everything to do with search. Which leads to `onClick={() => { search(); setRetryCount(); }}`. Then only the logging that is specifically dependent on retryCount will be expressed in that effect.